# Wordpress template div not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme that i'm building but i've hit a snag with some code and can't seem to get my div to expand correctly. I've tried clearing the floats at different positions, i've tried overflow: hidden, but nothing seems to work.

What i'm trying to do is have the content slide in from either side based on what header you click. The content is based on a wordpress post for each link. So the client can easilly edit it to any size.

Because of this it isn't viable to use pixels in the sizing of it. And i know that absolute positioning means that pixels are very nearly the only option.

I've messed with everything i can think of in firebug and just cannot get it to expand.

You'll find the site here: http://tinyurl.com/okd5wnf

However i couldn't get this to work either. Maybe that'll give you a clue as to what might be wrong.

I know it's a long winded post, and i apologise. If i have time later, i should be able to make a jsfiddle. However time is short at the moment.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Which part of the page are you trying to expand? I assume the text below the image gallery?

Comment: The white area. There is a div called "body-wrapper" (bad naming, i know) which contains the divs that will be sliding in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems stems from setting the `<div class="box"></div>`'s position property to `absolute`. Give the parent element(`<div id="body-wrapper"></div>`) `overflow-x:hidden;` to hide children that are not being displayed, and then use negative margins to position child elements within the viewport (the parent element). This is basically how most sliders work.

Comment: What negative margins, exactly? The ones on the "box" divs?

Comment: Oh, I should clarify. You'll want to create a wrapper element that is a child of the body-wrapper and that also encloses the "box" divs. Then, 'float' the box divs within the new wrapper element so that they are positioned horizontally (on the same line). Let's say the width of each box div is 150px, and thus the width of the new wrapper element is 150*3=450. Now you want to change the left margin of the new wrapper element to move the box divs around. margin-left:0px will show the first "box" div. margin-left:-150px will show the second "box" div and so on.

Comment: The essence is using negative margins to reposition child elements instead of manipulating the "left" property of absolutely positioned elements. position:absolute will remove the "box" divs from the natural flow, which is the cause of your problem.

Comment: I am putting everything back to before i messed around with the slider so i have a good place to start. If i still can't get it to work, i'll let you know. But so far this seems like the best example. Thank you very much. (I'd like to point out that you don't realise how little you know till you come here. I appreciate everyones help in this. )

Comment: This is essentially what i'm wanting to do. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/2uV2h/[/link]. However i can't seem to get the fiddle to work without absolutes. :/

Comment: @DanielRuxton I've whipped up a simple example for you. Have a look at it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CafeCoder/aRbQS/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove position `absolute` from `box` class. please also mention what desired layout you need for content. we will suggest you classes for that.

Comment: Doing that does not layer the divs correctly. They should be side by side offscreen.

Comment: The content needs to slide from left to right from that section of the page, essentially. But until i get the height problem solved i won't be able to move on.

Comment: When I remove position in box class it display content text and image in bottom . what you need?

Comment: It does that, however they layer underneath each other. If you click the header links, you'll see that they slide in and out, but underneath each other. I'm looking to have them all on the same position essentially. Just outside the page.

Comment: I am not getting you properly. Can you please elaborate more.. or add any image simply draw your layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40123/discussion-between-roopendra-and-daniel-ruxton)

Answer (score 0):

Romove position:absolute from div.box

I guess that's all.